# Maven can't resolve kafka dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

Intellij and Eclipse do not resolve dependencies for plugins (`maven-clean-plugin`, `maven-install-plugin`, ...) and for Kafka (`org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients`).

I have tried a lot of solutions:

1. try to install it locally using this command:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\kafka_jar\kafka-clients.jar \
   -DgroupId=org.apache-kafka -DartifactId=kafka-clients -Dversion=2.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
   ```

but I got other errors shown:

[image: in this picture]

2. Because I am working in a company, I had to use a proxy to let Maven access internet. in Intellij, I think I configured the proxy but I am not sure that Maven is using it to download (but marketplace is working and I could download plugins). or do you think it is the firewall who stop Maven?
3. I modified `settings.xml` multiple times adding proxy settings, and maven central but I get the same problem, this is `settings.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <settings>
     <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>
      </activeProfiles>
     <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>securecentral</id>
          <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the
             Maven Super POM -->
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>central</id>
              <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
            </repository>
          </repositories>
          <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
              <id>central</id>
              <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
          </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
      </profiles>
     <proxies>
      <!-- Proxy for HTTP -->
      <proxy>
       <id>optional</id>
       <active>true</active>
       <protocol>http</protocol>
       <username>myUsername</username>
       <password>myPassword</password>
       <host>host</host>
       <port>80</port>
       <nonProxyHosts>nonProxyHosts</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>

      <!-- Proxy for HTTPS -->
      <proxy>
       <id>optional</id>
       <active>true</active>
       <protocol>https</protocol>
       <username>myUsername</username>
       <password>myPassword</password>
       <host>host</host>
       <port>80</port>
       <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
     </proxies>


    </settings>
```

4. I tried also to change between Maven 2 and Maven 3. when I use Maven 2, the dependencies about plugins disappear but not Kafka.

Comment: Formatting and grammar edits

Comment: BTW, that's not the problem here but it's [`-DgroupId=org.apache.kafka`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.kafka%20a:kafka-clients) (with a '`.`') rather than `-DgroupId=org.apache-kafka` (with a '`-`').

Comment: thanks, I tried it but I got the same problem " Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have proxy/firewall issues. You may have misconfigured the proxy in your POM or your proxy/firewall may block your requests.

Speak with your admin (the one responsible for proxy/firewall) if the proxy allows such requests and if not, how to remedy the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Locate your maven settings.xml file - typically this is under `.m2` folder in your home directory (C:\Users\XYZ in Windows or /home/xyz in Mac/Linux).

Add below entry

```
<proxies>
<!-- proxy
 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
 |
 -->
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <!-- <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password> These may not be required -->
  <host>yourProxyHost</host>
  <port>yourProxyPort</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>*.company.com|127.0.0.1|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Make sure a `mvn clean install` works from a command prompt, and then check your IDE.